# how can test this method in junit?

Tags: java, junit

I wrote this method and I tried to test it but the results does not match:

```
public static int SearchByusername(ArrayList<Account> A, String username) {
    int exists = -1;
    int searchListLength = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
        if (A.get(i).getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            exists = i;
        } else {
            exists = -1;
        }
    }
    return exists;
}
```

the test method:

```
 public void TestSearchByusername() {
        ArrayList<Account> accountINFO = new ArrayList<>();
        Account user_1 = new Account("Sarah", "Naghi", "Sarh@hotmail.com", "0500000001", "Sarah", "Ss@12345678", 23);
        Account user_2 = new Account("Rawan", "Samer", "Rawan@hotmail.com", "0500000002", "RawanS", "Rr@12345678", 22);
        Account user_3 = new Account("Ragad", "Fahad", "Ragad@hotmail.com", "0500000003", "RagadFt", "Rr@12345678", 22);
        Account user_4 = new Account("Leen", "Saleh", "Leen@hotmail.com", "0500000004", "LeenS", "Ll@12345678", 23);
        accountINFO.add(user_1);
        accountINFO.add(user_2);
        accountINFO.add(user_3);
        accountINFO.add(user_4);

        // valid input
        String vaildUsername = "Sarah";
        // invalid input
        String invaildUsername = "Shaima";
        //test
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = SaudiGuide.SearchByusername(accountINFO, vaildUsername);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
   
    }
```

How I can do a junit test in above method if anyone can help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: That's because you have a bug in your method. It'll always return `-1` unless the element that you're searching for is the very last element in the list.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you have a valid test, which indicates it has failed due to a bug in your method under test.

Comment: thank you but I don't get why it always returns -1. the method returns the index if the username exists in the LinkedList array if it does not exist return -1 and I think how I can make the expected results take more than one value.

Comment: Which parameter of Account constructor is the username?

Comment: @Javaluca the five parameter

Comment: Note that using `int` to represent true/false is an extreme antipattern—the `boolean` type exists specifically to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int SearchByusername(ArrayList<Account> A, String username) {
    
    int searchListLength = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {

        if (A.get(i).getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            return i;
        }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thank you and I appreciate your answer. I have one question the expected result should be the index of the username I search about right?  okay if I want the expected result to be all the indexes of the array how I can do it? I mean any name I search for if it is in the array the test it should be right

Comment: public static boolean SearchByusername(ArrayList<Account> A, String username) {
    
    int searchListLength = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {

        if (!A.get(i).getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}